How to mock embed.FS?
I have a module a.go, which reads data from a bunch of text files:
//go:embed *.txt
var textFiles embed.FS

func DoSomething() fs.FS {
    fmt.Println(textFiles)
}

In other module, I use DoSomething() inside another function, like so:
func OtherF() {
    DoSomething()
}

I need to test OtherF, but for that I need to mock the contents of textFiles - how to achieve this?
I tried replacing the package variable, but it's private so it didn't work.

There is no need to "mock" that. Just use what you embed. There is no runtime things that could change and would need mocking.

An easy way to simulate a mocked file system in memory for testing is to use (testing/fstest).MapFS, which implements the fs.FS file system interface. A common method would be to simply swap out the concrete value with a stubbed implementation conforming to the same interface during test execution.
However, unfortunately, you cannot directly use fs.FS as the declared type of a variable annotated with a //go:embed directive; to do so will result in a compile-time error. Attempting to compile:
//go:embed mydir/*
var data fs.FS

yields the following compiler error:
./mockfs.go:9:5: go:embed cannot apply to var of type fs.FS


As a workaround for this problem, one common method would be to instead indirect access to the embed.FS or stubbed fs.FS via a function which can be replaced:

hide access to the embed.FS behind a function that type converts embed.FS to fs.FS (trivial, as the former implements the latter)
use that function to retrieve a handle for the target file system whenever a lookup in the embedded (or stubbed) file system is performed
arrange for the function to return the mocked file system when running in tests, either by swapping out or detecting presence of the test framework, and responding accordingly.

Here is some example code that would achieve this through swapping out the function:
//go:embed mydir/*
var data embed.FS

// getFS can be swapped at runtime to stub out a file system
// for test purposes.
var getFS = func() fs.FS {
    return data
}

and, in your test case, you can temporarily swap out getFS with your mocked file system (assuming your tests are in the same package):
func MyTest(t *testing.T) {
    origFS := getFS
    getFS = func() fs.FS {
        return fstest.MapFS{
            "mydir/someFile.txt": &fstest.MapFile{},
        }
    }
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        getFS = origFS
    })

    // your test logic here...
}

Working example in the Go playground – however, note that in this example the //go:embed directive has been mangled, as the playground does not appear to support including both additional files (to allow the embed to be resolved) and execute embedded test cases. This code should work locally if you run it with some sample data in the mydir/ subdirectory.

Other methods are possible if they swap behaviour during tests (e.g. an environment variable) or detection of the Go testing framework. The code example below does the latter, although suffers from the (slight) downside that the mocked file system definition is then separated in code from the test cases that test it.
func getFS() fs.FS {
    if flag.Lookup("test.v") == nil {
        return data
    } else {
        return fstest.MapFS{
            "mydir/someFile.txt": &fstest.MapFile{},
        }
    }
}

